# how to delete record recursively using cursor

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, db2

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  WRK.PURGE_ACH_BATCH_TAB_1()
LANGUAGE SQL

BEGIN
    -- Declare cursor
    DECLARE v_CNT_BLOCK INTEGER;
    DECLARE Ac_no BIGINT;
    DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000'; 
    DECLARE mycur cursor for 
        SELECT t.TNX_Ac_no
        FROM WRK.BATCH_TAB1 c
            INNER JOIN WRK.BATCH_TAB t
                ON c.BATCH_ID = t.BATCH_ID
                    AND c.PROCESS_ID = t.process_ID
        WHERE c.BATCH_START_TS < (CURRENT DATE -7 days); 

    set v_CNT_BLOCK = 0;
    open mycur;

    FETCH FROM mycur INTO Ac_no;
    WHILE(SQLSTATE = '00000') DO
        DELETE FROM WRK.BATCH_TAB1 b WHERE b.TNX_Ac_no = Ac_no;
        SET v_CNT_BLOCK=v_CNT_BLOCK+1;
        if v_CNT_BLOCK >= 5 then
            set v_CNT_BLOCK = 0;
            commit;
        end if;

        FETCH FROM mycur INTO Ac_no;  

    END WHILE; 

    CLOSE mycur; 

    commit; 

END
@
```

I have millions of record but am fetching all records one at time..  later am fetching one by one for deletion. Here my question is does Selecting all millions of records at once will cause any performance issue. How to select record recursivEly so that I can take 50k records first and delete all.. Latar next 50k and so on..

Comment: Which do you have, MySQL or DB2?  They're vastly different.  Deleting by cursor is probably the least performant (overall) option - are you sure a regular searched `DELETE` isn't going to work?  Especially if you have an index on the primary search column.  Doing really small transactions like that won't help you much either.  For that matter, if you're doing nothing but deleting here (no auditing tables or triggers, etc), just run this without a transaction.   DB2 at least allows `FETCH FIRST 5000 ROWS` on lots of things.

Comment: Hi am using db2 only

Comment: Then please remove the incorrect tag.  What version and platform, please?  Why is this in a transaction?  You don't appear to be doing anything else with the info, and you won't be able to reverse chunks.  Note that [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) has a very specific meaning, and this isn't it - you're really doing things iteratively.  Are you sure a regular searched delete will take too long?  Do you have an index starting with `Batch_Tab1.batch_start_ts`?  Is it important that there are matching records in `Batch_Tab`, or do you delete those too?

Comment: Am not deleting those Clock.... i will be keeping the things there.. only  gonna delete from BATCH_TAB1 table. this has composite key from BATCH_TAB.... so for iterating the value do we must need of index.. is there is any other alternate wihout using index.since i dont have index..

Comment: If you want to access something fast on a db, it's usually good to have an index to cover any keys(what order the columns is in is important, too).  You don't usually explicitly query over it, the db will automatically pick it up.  If you're purging last week's records, do you actually need to check if they've been processed or whatever (have records in `Batch_Tab`), or everything in `Batch_Tab1` should be deleted regardless (just delete based off date range)?